# Text.Length is not working to find length of String for a webElement

Tags: c#, selenium

value of ​"total" is 0 here in this case :
I am not sure why it's not working ?

```
List<IWebElement> list = new List<IWebElement>(); 
list =  ABCPageObject.AbcTextArea().ToList();

foreach (IWebElement Option in list)
{
    Option.Click();
    Option.Clear();
    Option.SendKeys("ThisisTheasdfdsaOutput1234567890ThisisTheVWXYZer!O@ut#pu$tT%hi^sis&The*Tw(i)t<t>er[O]u{t}p/utT/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
foreach(IWebElement Option in list)
{
    var total = Option.Text.Length;
    // total is 0 here when we debug 

    if(total == 116)
    {
        Utility.Logger.Write("Add Out");
    }

}
```

Comment: What node type is each element in `list`?

Comment: textarea , I have only two elements in the list. Both elements are in two different div  , I can click on them, clear them but text.length is not working

Comment: Try using the value attribute to get the "text" of the text area.  Not familiar with C# syntax, but something like Option.getAttribute("value"), and then check the length of that?

Comment: Another option to try is Option.GetAttribute("textLength") and see if that works, the issue is that there is no "text" between the <textarea> tags.

Comment: Yes, you are correct , it worked well. string AbcString = Option.GetAttribute("value");
   var TotalLength = AbcString.Count();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check a `value` attributte instead of `text()`.
A value of `input` and `textarea` tags are stored in `value` attributte.
Please see a below simple test that shows that.
Here is a [simple test page](https://jsfiddle.net/f89zxd1w/) which contains two fields - `input` and `textarea`

```
<div>
  <textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="myinput" />
</div>
```

---

Here is a simple test code (in java):

```
driver.get("https://jsfiddle.net/f89zxd1w/");
driver.switchTo().frame("result");

driver.findElement(By.id("mytextarea")).sendKeys("Some text");

driver.findElement(By.id("myinput")).sendKeys("Some other text");

WebElement textArea = driver.findElement(By.id("mytextarea"));
String areaText = textArea.getText();
String areaValue = textArea.getAttribute("value");

System.out.format("Area text = %s\n", areaText);
System.out.format("Area value = %s\n", areaValue);

WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.id("myinput"));
String inputText = input.getText();
String inputValue = input.getAttribute("value");

System.out.format("Input text = %s\n", inputText);
System.out.format("Input value = %s\n", inputValue);
```

---

And a result is:

```
Area text = 
Area value = Some text
Input text = 
Input value = Some other text
```

Comment: string AbcString = Option.GetAttribute("value");
                var TotalLength = AbcString.Count();, worked, thanks you so much